# Warning: Invalid stream: "FormatError: Bad FCHECK in flate stream: 120, 239" on PDF response from springboot API after dropzone upload

Tags: angularjs, angular, pdf, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone to send files to a springboot api, which processes those files and returns a pdf response, which I want to display on my angular front-end. Everything works fine until time to display the pdf, when it renders a blank pdf (with the correct number of pages) along with the warnings in console:

```
Warning: Indexing all PDF objects pdf.worker.min.js:1
Warning: Invalid stream: "FormatError: Bad FCHECK in flate stream: 120, 239"
```

I know that the pdf itself is not corrupt, because when I make a get request to the API to retrieve the stored version of the same pdf, it is not corrupt and renders fine.

I have tried using TextEncoder:

```
let enc = new TextEncoder();
this.masterPdf = enc.encode(event[1])
```

using FileReader:

```
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {
      var arrayBuffer = this.result;
      self.masterPdf = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
      console.log(self.masterPdf);
      self.masterShow = true;
  }
  var blob = new Blob([event[1]], {type:'application/pdf'});
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

and using StringToBytes:

```
let strToByteArr = stringToBytes(event[1]);
this.masterPdf = new Uint8Array(strToByteArr);
```

event in all of these cases is the response, here it is below (of course the pdf string is actually much longer):

```
0: File(1237) {upload: {…}, status: "success", accepted: true, processing: true, xhr: XMLHttpRequest, …}
1:"%PDF-1.7↵%����↵1 0 obj↵<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(en-US) /StructTreeRoot 12 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>/Metadata 32 0 R/ViewerPreferences 33 0 R>>↵endobj↵2 0 obj↵<</Type/Pages/Count 2/Kids[ 3 0 R 9 0 R] >>↵endobj↵3 0 obj↵<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</Font<</F1 5 0 R>>/ExtGState<</GS7 7 0 R/GS8 8 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 612 792] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<</Type/Group/S/Transparency/CS/DeviceRGB>>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>>↵endobj↵4 0 obj↵<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 3808>>↵stream
2: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: true, loaded: 99282, total: 99282, type: "load", …}
```

I did check those particular bytes (120-239) in the valid file returned versus the invalid one, and they are different, but the invalid one just looked like normal numbers.

Answer (score 5):

When requesting a PDF from an API, set the request's response type to 'blob'. The default type is application/json.

Once the file has been received, create a blob using the response's data then use the blob to create a url.

```
  let blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'})
  let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
```

Comment: Hello @depiction, one small question, after having this url variable, what should we do then? pass this URL variable to the getDocument() function? I'm a rookie with PDF.js and it isn't clear to me, thank you so much.

Comment: @Emmanuel_M This has nothing to do with PDF.js. Just add a HTML link to the url that the user can click to open the PDF.